# Make ExtJS input field lose focus

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a `numberfield` input which I want to lose focus when the user hits the enter key.

Here's the current config:

```
{
  xtype: 'numberfield',
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 99999,
  hideTrigger: true,
  keyNavEnabled: false,
  mouseWheelEnabled: false,
  enableKeyEvents: true,

  listeners: {
    specialkey: function(f, e) {
      if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER)
        f.blur();
    }
  }
}
```

The `specialkey` handler works, calling `blur()` as expected, but the only result is that the caret disappears from the input (indicating that the DOM text input element has been blurred).  The field still has all the `x-form-focus` etc css classes, and examining the object shows that the private `hasFocus` property is still true.

Any suggestions?

I have tried calling `f.onBlur()` explicitly after the `blur()` call, but it made no difference.

(btw the field does not belong to a form so there is no form to submit.)

Comment: What about focusing another component? Even its parent container...

Comment: @VoidMain - cheers, but same result as calling blur()

Comment: If you call `f.up().focus();` it doesn't make `f` lose its focused class?

Comment: Quick question: Are you calling `f.up().focus()` alone or are you calling `f.blur()` before? local testing shows that, if i call `f.blur()` the call to `f.up().focus()` its, somehow, ignored...

Comment: @VoidMain focus() alone, but trying both gives the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix.  The issue is caused by a weird behavior in the Ext.form.field.Trigger class where they don't trigger `'triggerBlur()'` when the regular `'blur()'` function is called.  Very interesting:

```
listeners: {
    specialkey: function(f, e) {
        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER)
        {
            f.triggerBlur();
            f.blur();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it certainly works, but given that triggerBlur is private, it looks like an extjs bug.  I'll pass this on to ExtJS support.

Comment: by the way this will fix your issue by just putting triggerBlur() in your code.

Comment: Yeah.  It's definately a bug, but this is the fix.

Comment: Make sure you ask all about all bugs you find on SO.  There are some very smart people here who can fix them for you sometimes much faster or better than their support can in my experience.

Comment: Indeed, SO is first place to ask.  In fact I had forgotten we had a support subscription for extjs :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
specialkey: function(field,events) {
    if (events.getKey() == events.ENTER) {
        var nextfld = field.nextSibling(); 
        nextfld.focus(true,100);
    }
}
```

specialkey -  is a listener of component like textfield,textare,datefield etc,

events.getKey -  gets the user keyboard input

events.ENTER -  i used this for that will be triggered when "ENTER" in keyboard

field.nextSibling - field refers to current component, and nextSibling property of component to tell who will be the next component

lastly is the nextfld.focus to focus the next component